# How to print a particular column from tabular data

Tags: arrays, perl, data-structures, perl-data-structures

I'm Trying to print columns from data by using index key value in the outer part of a foreach loop.

```
my @col;
foreach(<DATA>){
    @x = split(' ',$_);
@xz = ($x[0],$x[1],$x[2]) ;
    #print "$x[0]\n"; This is working but i'm not expect this.
push(@col,@xz);
} 
print "$col[0]\n";
__DATA__
7       2       3

3       2       8

6       7       2
```

I expect the output is

```
7 3 6
```

How can i do it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
my @col;
while (<DATA>) {
    push @col, (split ' ')[0];
    # push @col, /(\S+)/; # split alternative
}
print "@col\n";

__DATA__
7       2       3

3       2       8

6       7       2
```

output

```
7 3 6
```

Answer (score 3):

Always use `use strict;` and `use warnings;`!!

You have a couple of issues:

```
push( @col, @xz );
```

In this case, you're *losing* your information in `@xz` array. After this loop, you end up with a single array that looks like this:

```
@col = ( 7, 2, 3, 3, 2, 8, 6, 7, 2);
```

So, when you print:

```
print "$col[0]\n";
```

You get that zeroth element: 7.

We can preserve the structure of the data by using a [reference](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlreftut.html):

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#
    use strict;             # Lets you know when you misspell variable names
    use warnings;           # Warns of issues (using undefined variables

    use feature qw(say);
    use Data::Dumper;

    my @columns;
    for my $data ( <DATA> ) {
        my @data_list = split /\s+/, $data;
        push @columns, \@data_list;
}

say Dumper \@columns;

__DATA__
7       2       3
3       2       8
6       7       2
```

Here you see I've included [Data::Dumper](http://perldoc.perl.org/Data/Dumper.html) to print out the structure of `@columns`:

```
$VAR1 = [
          [
            '7',
            '2',
            '3'
          ],
          [
            '3',
            '2',
            '8'
          ],
          [
            '6',
            '7',
            '2'
          ]
      ];
```

As you can see, each entry in the `@columns` array is now another array. However, printing out `$columns[0]` array reference isn't going to print what you want. Instead, it's going to print the zeroth array reference: 7, 2, 3, and not the zeroth element of each array reference: 7, 3, 6.

To do that, we need a *subroutine* that will go through `@columns` and print out the the zeroth entry of each of the arrays. Here I'm creating a subroutine called `fetch_index` that will fetch the passed index of the passed array:

```
#! /usr/bin/env perl
#
    use strict;             # Lets you know when you misspell variable names
    use warnings;           # Warns of issues (using undefined variables

    use feature qw(say);
    use Data::Dumper;

    my @columns;
    for my $data ( <DATA> ) {
        my @data_list = split /\s*/, $data;
        push @columns, \@data_list;
}

say join ", ", fetch_index( 0, @columns );

sub fetch_index {
    my $entry = shift;     #Entry you want from all arrays
    my @array = @_;

    my @values;

    for my $array_ref ( @array ) {
        push @values, ${array_ref}->[$entry];
    }
    return @values;
}

__DATA__
7       2       3
3       2       8
6       7       2
```

The subroutine merely goes through each array reference I've stored in my array, and fetched the `$entry` value from that array reference. I push those into my `@values` array and return that.

Comment: excellent explanation of what went wrong and how to make it right.

Comment: Regarding `split()`, `\s+` is (almost?) always better than `\s*` https://eval.in/238890

Answer (score 0):

Once you've absorbed the information about anonymous arrays and references in the other excellent posts here, you can start to have fun. *e.g.* you can often get a one liner approach to work:

```
perl -nE 'say [split]->[1] ' col_data.txt
```

would loop (`-n` creates an implicit `while(){}` loop) through the data in `col_data.txt`, `split` the topic variable (`$_`) creating a series of anonymous  arrays from each row and then print the second element, or "column" for example.

You can use the [autosplit command line option (`-a`)](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches) to split each row into an array called `@F` (mnemonic: "`F`" for "Field"). In later versions of `perl`, the `-a` implies the implicit `while` loop (`-n`):

```
perl -anE 'say $F[1] ' col_data.txt
```

would be the equivalent of the previous command - printing the second column:

**output**:

```
2
2
7
```

There is a famous and short perl workalike for `cut` that is a more featureful variaton on this theme, and there is [this Perl Monks thread](http://www.perlmonks.org/?node_id=448559).

Comment: `perl -anE 'say $F[1] if /\S/'` would skip blank lines.

Answer (score 0):

`perl -a -F' ' -ne 'print "$F[0]\n";'  data.txt`

> here you $F[0] is field you can change it accordingly you will get the expected output

Answer (score -1):

You were pretty close I think.  This is what I did (edited to reflect comments from @Borodin):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

sub getColumn {
  my ($data, $col) = @_;
  my @output = map $_->[$col], @{$data};
  return @output;
}

my @data;
while (<DATA>){
    push(@data, [split(' ',$_)]);
}
print join(' ', getColumn(\@data, 0), "\n");
print join(' ', getColumn(\@data, 1), "\n");
print join(' ', getColumn(\@data, 2), "\n");

__DATA__
7       2       3
3       2       8
6       7       2
```

That subroutine `getColumn` should let you retrieve any arbitrary column.  When I ran it with your data I got this for output:

```
7 3 6
2 2 7
3 8 2
```

Comment: I'd also cleanup those print statements.  If you don;t mind I'll edit your post with that update.

Comment: Your program won't compile as it stands because there is no `say` without a `use feature 'say'` or `use 5.010` or similar. You really should have `use strict` and `use warnings` in place as well. Is there a reason why you used `for` instead of `while` to read the file? And the `getColumn` subroutine is unnecessary. If you really want to keep it then it can be written `map $_->[$col], @{$data}`.

Comment: @Borodin Good comments - thanks for the catches.  Your points are all valid - the only thing I can say about the `for` vs. `while` issue was I was trying to minimize deviations from OP's code.